# C# programming for a label link?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok here is my problem[or you can sat awkward question), I have a label I have created a link for it, working example below:

```
string strLinkBegin = "<a href='";
            //string strLinkMid = "'>";
            string strLinkMid = "' target='_blank'>";
            string strLinkEnd = "</a>";
            string strQuerystring = ""; 
 strQuerystring = "somePage.aspx" + "?AMode=" + "Update" + "&someID=" + hdnsomeLink.Value;
 lblFromDesc.Text = strLinkBegin + strQuerystring + strLinkMid + hdnFromDescText.Value + strLinkEnd;
```

**Real question:**  can I write something similar to code you see below in a label and when user clicks it it executes? I know I can program through link button but was interested if its possible to do the same thing in a label.

```
someclass WTRadWindow = new someclass();
WTRadWindow.OpenUpdateForm(Page, hdnToDescLinkURL.Value, 350, 263);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Label` control cannot contain HTML text, it is designed to display plain text.

As discussed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12604684/1159478), the most appropriate solution would be to use the `Hyperlink` Control.

If it's really important for you to generate the HTML as a string and then add it to the page you would need to use the `LiteralControl`.  If you just used that instead of a label your existing code should work just fine.  I want to mention though that literal controls should be used sparingly, and that it really isn't appropriate in this situation.  So much of what makes ASP great is that you *don't* need to create HTML as a string.

Answer (score 1):

To start with you could take a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx

It does, to me at least, seem as if you are using the wrong control to achieve what you are after, in that putting a html link into a `Label` seems to be a slight misuse of the control. The `HyperLink` control is what first came to mind when reading your question. That is why I gave you the link.

Whether or not it is a misuse, I think it is not of great importance, but the `HyperLink` control should provide what you are wanting.

Comment: yes I do already have it programmed for hyperlink but was curios to know if its achievable through label also in someway.

Comment: Sorry, please forgive me but I am not understanding exactly what you mean. The example c# does not show me how they work together, for example, how does `WTRadWindow` use the `Label` control? Try explaining further in your question so that you describe things deeper and clearer if possible.